# top hat filter running time

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem with speed of a top hat filter. In an IEEE transaction paper, the running time of top hat applied to an image with resolution 320× 256 is estimated 0.0062 second with MATLAB software on a PC with 8-GB memory and 4-GHz Intel i7 processor. table_time I run the following code with openCV on a laptop with 6-GB memory and 2.6-GHz Intel i5 processor for this image with the same resolution: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FtNm.jpg)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double t0 = (double)getTickCount();
    Mat src,dst;
    src=imread("E:/tree.jpg",0);
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,Size(15,15));
    morphologyEx(src,dst,MORPH_TOPHAT,element,Point(-1,-1));
    double elapsed=((double)getTickCount()-t0)/getTickFrequency();
    cout<<elapsed<<"second"<<"\n";
    return -1;}
```

It takes .05375 second. In spite of the the fact that C++ and openCV are fast, but why the running time of top hat is 6 ms in matlab and 54 ms in opencv. how I could accelerate it?

Comment: First why do you include imread imread in ellapse time? Second if you use opencl sometime code is compiled during runtime at first call check ellpased time for second call. As strukmen said check getbuildinformation to konw what opencv version you are using

Comment: As already mentioned, you measured the reading time + the filter time. As a general comment, [benchmarking](http://mattwarren.org/2014/09/19/the-art-of-benchmarking/) computation time is complex, especially with languages that use high level mechanism like just-in-time compilation. The almost only fair comparison is to execute the two programs (which produce the same result) on the same machine  and in addition by using correct benchmark methods to deal with language specificity. In general, the language does not matter, only the implementation. That should deal with the why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my test result on my laptop ( Intel(R)_Core(TM)_i5-3230M_CPU_@_2.60GHz)

0.00129578 seconds!!

i think the most important thing is how did you compile OpenCV. there is many options. i attached my output of `getBuildInformation()`

test code (improved version of your code)

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main() {

    Mat src, dst;
    src = imread("tree.jpg", 0);
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(15, 15));
    double elapsed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double t0 = (double)getTickCount();
        morphologyEx(src, dst, MORPH_TOPHAT, element, Point(-1, -1));
        elapsed += ((double)getTickCount() - t0) / getTickFrequency();
    }

    cout << elapsed / 100 << " seconds" << "\n";
    cout << getBuildInformation();
    imshow("result", dst);
    waitKey();
    return -1;
}
```

output of the test code

```
0.00129578 seconds

General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0-dev =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            D:/git/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2016-05-27T19:59:05Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.10586 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.5.0-rc3
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1900

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 19.0.23506.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:AVX /Oi  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:AVX /Oi  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:AVX /Oi    /MP4  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /arch:AVX /Oi    /MP4  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 D:/git/pthreadVC2.lib
    3rdparty dependencies:       zlib libjpeg libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired cvblobslib dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching tracking ayvos java
    Disabled:                    world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 python3 viz cvv hdf matlab sfm

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        NO
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.19)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           NO
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      codec:                     YES (ver 56.41.100)
      format:                    YES (ver 56.36.101)
      util:                      YES (ver 54.27.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 3.1.101)
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              YES
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     NO
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  YES
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
    Include path:                D:/git/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Use AMDFFT:                  NO
    Use AMDBLAS:                 NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.11)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         C:/Program Files/apache-ant/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.6)
    JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              YES

  Install path:                  D:/opencv-build/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              D:/opencv-build
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This number means almost nothing in this case. Different machines, no information about how they benchmarked or what parameters they used. I have no doubt that OpenCV should be as fast as Matlab if not faster but my point is to put emphasis on first the difficulty to make proper benchmark especially with [JVM language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) and second in most of the cases the implementation matters more than the programming language. My second point is general as OpenCV is built to have good performance in computer vision.

Answer (score 1):

First and most important, you are counting the image loading from the disk, which is usually the slowest part of the program. If you want to compare to the paper, time only the tophat function without anything else.

Furthermore, there are many other compiling options which can effect this. You can try to compile OpenCV with all kind of processor specific optimization, CUDA, etc.. which can have a great effect.