# alternate function for erode to reduce the processing time

Tags: opencv, image-processing, frame-rate

I am working with the object detection for which the images from the camera are obtained at 30fps, which indicates that the my processing speed for the each frame should be 0.03seconds. Since I am using the erode function, the processing time has increased, thereby processing of the images are delayed fraction of seconds which is not in real time. So I am looking for some function to replace the erode which takes less processing time. [image: before applying erode function] 
[image: after applying erode function]..
I want the some function that can eliminate the noise but give me the similar output of the erode function.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37508183/5294258) i think `cv::erode` runs fast enough.

Comment: You can try to use the SMIL library, it is super optimized.

Comment: @FiReTiTi  Can you tell what is SMIL library?

Comment: Here it is: https://smil.cmm.mines-paristech.fr/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

GPU version should do the trick http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cudafilters/doc/filtering.html#cuda-createmorphologyfilter